# will be fixed in 5.50.2 : No more receipt_text_renewal field in notification mail of a renewal in v. 5.50.1

Tags: civimember, joomla, issues

After upgrading to v. 5.50.1 (Joomla!), we don't find anymore the field texarea to add some word in the notification email of a renewal.

Step to reproduce :

1. Go to membership
2. click on renew
3. tick Send Confirmation and Receipt?
4. there is no field ta add some text

I try to change receipt_text_renewal to receipt_text in MembershipRenewal.tpl on line 127 but the written text wasn't sent by email.

Is this an issue ?

Comment: "I try to change receipt_text_renewal to receipt_text in MembershipRenewal.tpl on line 127 but the written text wasn't sent by email." : It didn't work because my model had not been fixed and still contained receipt_text_renewal instead of receipt_text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23726. It will be fixed in 5.50.2

Comment: Many thanks. The patch on https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23729/files works fine.